# Como puedo capturar un numero por teclado y llevarla a una variable de tipo float

Tags: c#

Buenos días, tengo entendido que cuando capturo un dato por teclado debo convertirlo así:

```
entero1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())
```

ahora mi pregunta es como puedo hacerlo si el dato que necesito es decimal, lo intento de esta manera, pero la sintaxis no me permite continuar.

```
numero = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Tu código es correcto. De que tipo es `numero`? debe ser `double` para que te funcione

Comment: ¿Decimal, float o double? Decimal debe usarse para tipos números con decimales con precisión fija por ejemplo monedas. Float y Double para precisión variable, donde se peuden tener muchísimos decimales, double tiene más capacidad y es el tipo de dato comúnmente utilizado frente al float

Comment: requiero en sí solo sumar dos numeros uno entero y otro decimal, no se como capturar el decimal

Comment: Asumiré entonces que te refieres a numeros de tipo `Double`

Comment: Carlos es hacer esto     Console.WriteLine("ingrese entero");
                    numero = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("ingrese decimal");
                    numerodecimal = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                }

Comment: Hola jorge, Como te menciono en la respuesta, no uses `Convert`. Por otro lado en tu pregunta no mencionas de que tipo es `numero`. Por favor edita tu pregunta para colocar todo el código relevante

Comment: Ya me dió , usando double  en la variable numero, ya que la estaba declarando de tipo float, uso el convert, porque el profesor que nos da clase, asi nos enseñó a capturar un dato de tipo string y pasarlo a int ya que por teclado se recibe un string o asi lo entiendo, pero tú ayuda me compiló , muchas gracias   , me gustaría cambiar eso, pero por ahora estoy aprendiendo jeje

Comment: Si, al final entendí bien a que te referias, ya actualicé mi respuesta

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64524/discussion-between-carlos-munoz-and-jorge).

Comment: Posible duplicado de [como leer un dato de tipo long en una linea de codigo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/98142/como-leer-un-dato-de-tipo-long-en-una-linea-de-codigo)

Comment: Amigo Carlos Muñoz estoy haciendo la suma, y logré que compilara pero ahora me trae es un resultado erroneo    Console.WriteLine("ingrese entero");
            int numeroentero = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("ingrese decimal");
            long numeroDecimal = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            long suma = numeroDecimal + numeroentero;
            Console.WriteLine(suma);
            Console.ReadLine();

Answer (score 2):

No uses la clase `Convert` si tratas de parsear un texto que haya sido ingresado por el usuario debido a que es posible que el texto no sea un valor válido del tipo de dato que quieres obtener. En lugar utiliza el método `TryParse()` del tipo de dato destino.

Ejemplo con el caso de `Single` (en C# alias `float`)

C# 7 o superior

```
if (Single.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out float numero))
{
    // Acá la variable numero tiene el valor asignado
}
else
{
    // No se pudo converir el dato ingresado por el usuario en float
}
```

C# 6 o inferior

```
float result;
if (Single.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numero))
{
    // Acá la variable numero tiene el valor asignado
}
else
{
    // No se pudo converir el dato ingresado por el usuario en float
}
```

Lo mismo puedes hacer en el caso de `decimal` y `double`, los 3 tipos de datos tienen el método `TryParse()`

Comment: Lo probaré , muchas gracias por su ayuda.