# Como leer un dato de tipo long en una línea de código

Tags: c#

¿Cómo puedo leer por teclado este decimal: 5.3? Ya que necesito sumar un número entero con uno decimal.

```
Console.WriteLine("ingrese entero");
int numeroentero = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("ingrese decimal");
numeroDecimal = ???????
```

Comment: probaste con console.readline()? tiro algun error?

Comment: si asi :  numeroDecimal = Console.ReadLine(); dice que no se puede convertir explicitamente string a long

Comment: Tienes que hacer la conversion implicita. Sabes como o lo ponemos como respuesta?

Comment: Ya has hecho esta misma pregunta pero para float. En la respuesta que te coloqué te mencioné que lo msimo es para decimal, float, o double.

Answer (score 1):

Long es un numero entero de 64 bits, no es un numero decimal, para decimal usa decimal, double o float

así sería lo que estas buscando

```
numeroDecimal = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

aquí una referencia a los tipos de datos
https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/ms228360(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta para el long System.Int64  entero, 8 bytes con signo

```
num = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Tambien te serviría :

```
long longValue1 = 4_294_967_296;
Console.WriteLine(longValue1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Como ya te mencioné en la otra pregunta que hiciste **no uses** la clase `Convert`

Usa `<Tipo>.TryParse()` en su lugar

Y por cierto `long` es un número entero de 64 bits, en su lugar usa la clase `Decimal`

Ejemplo:

```
Console.WriteLine("ingrese entero");
int numeroEntero;
if (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numeroEntero))
{
    throw new Exception("El número ingresado no es un entero");
}

Console.WriteLine("ingrese decimal");
decimal numeroDecimal;
if (!Decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numeroDecimal))
{
    throw new Exception("El número ingresado no es un decimal");
}

var suma  = numeroEntero + numeroDecimal;
```